# Unable to Boot Kernel within Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 64 Bit OS. After Installation when I am running Kitematic(Alpha), its getting stucked at 99% and Default Preview is throwing me Error in Attached Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: In your BIOS check if VT-x is enabled or not.

Comment: See this [article](https://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/virtualbox/this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-unable-to-boot-please-use-a-kernel-appropriate-for-your-cpu/)

Comment: @TarunLalwani Enabled VT-x BIOS and still the issue is same.
My System Configuration is:-
64 Bit OS, 4 GB RAM, Intel Core 2 CPU (Processor)

Comment: @TarunLalwani pressed F10 BIOS Options and enable the VT-x CheckBox, its working for me now and I am able to download the Images. Please make it in Answer and I will give you +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your machine enter the BIOS settings and enable VT-x settings. This is required for some virtualization features

> Intel VT (Virtualization Technology) is the company's hardware assistance for processors running virtualization platforms.
>
> Intel VT includes a series of extensions for hardware virtualization. The Intel VT-x extensions are probably the best recognized extensions, adding migration, priority and memory handling capabilities to a wide range of Intel processors. By comparison, the VT-d extensions add virtualization support to Intel chipsets that can assign specific I/O devices to specific virtual machines (VM)s, while the VT-c extensions bring better virtualization support to I/O devices such as network switches.